# Activity change icon programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I have 2 activities and they must be run separately.
Now, I'm starting second activity using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

[image: screenshot of the result].

**QUESTION:** How can I change icons of the activities?
As I remember, it's possible, as Google Chrome used them before. How this feature called?

---

**UPDATE:** Icons are dynamic, so I need to change them programmatically

Comment: Just in case: did you try setting `android:icon` for each activity separately?

Comment: @Shaishav icons are dynamic, they must be set programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by [`ActivityManager.TaskDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription.html)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100891/3815843

---

<sub>PS: On Android running applications are called "Recent Apps". I always googled `Task manager`, `Intent manager`. That's why I didn't found any info</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I think you question is duplicated. See other same question.

**[This, for example!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249542/4133301)**

Answer (score -2):

Just set `android:icon` for each activity separately in manifest. Works for me.

Comment: Question start with Activity change icon programmatically!

Comment: My bad, missed that